# Laravel 6.0 Shopping Cart Package: Missing required parameters for [Route: cart.update] [URI: {rowId}]

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, cart, laravel-blade

I have two methods. One increases the quantity of the products in the cart. The other decreases the quantity.

```
{{-- INCREASE PRODUCT QUANTITY --}}
      <form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf 
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $product->id }}"> 
        <input name="name" type="hidden" value="{{ $product->name }}"> 
        <input name="price" type="hidden" value="{{ $product->price }}"> 
        <button class="bg-success text-white" style="width: 2rem;"><strong>+</strong></button>
      </form>
      {{-- END INCREASE PRODUCT QUANTITY --}}

      {{-- DECREASE PRODUCT QUANTITY --}}
      <form action="{{ route('cart.update', $product->rowId) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
        <button class="bg-danger text-white" style="width: 2rem;"><strong>-</strong></button>
      </form>
      {{-- END DECREASE PRODUCT QUANTITY --}}
```

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Cart::add(
            $request->id, 
            $request->name,
            1,
            $request->price 
            )
        ->associate('App\Product');

        return back()->with('quantityIncreasedMessage', 'Quantity has been increased.'); 
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Product $rowId)
    {
        $product = Cart::get($rowId);

        Cart::update($rowId, $product->qty - 1);

        return back()->with('quantityDecreasedMessage', 'Quantity has been decreased.'); 
    }
}
```

```
// increases product quantity in the cart
Route::post('/', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');

// decreases product quantity in the cart
Route::patch('/{rowId}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

The method that increases the quantity works as expected (cart.store). However, when calling the method that decreases the quantity (cart.update), I get the following:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: cart.update] [URI: {rowId}].
```

Does anyone that's familiar with this package know what's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here `action="{{ route('cart.update') }}"`, you need to pass a parameter with action route. like: `action="{{ route('cart.update', $product->id) }}"`

Comment: Also, I think you need to modify update function, before $rowId add type, means add Product model name.

Comment: I've made your suggested changes but I still get the same error. Please see above.

Comment: It's not   $product->rowId, replace it with $product->id. Correct one:  `<form action="{{ route('cart.update', $product->id) }}" method="POST">`

Comment: I changed it and now I get this error: ```array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer```. On my other project with this cart package I had to use rowId instead of id. Why would it be different now? Thanks

Comment: You have to pass an attribute of the product, the attribute is id, so you need to pass $product->id. and finally, replace `$product = Cart::get($rowId);` with `$product = Cart::get($rowId->id);` in update function.

Comment: I now get this error: The cart does not contain rowId 1. My update function is this: ```public function update(Request $request, Product $rowId)
    {
        $product = Cart::get($rowId->id);
        Cart::update($rowId, $product->qty - 1);
        
        return back()->with('quantityDecreasedMessage', 'Product quantity has been decreased.');
    }```

Comment: `$product->update([
    'qty' => $product->qty-1
]);`.  If qty is your column name